# Alternative to plotly scatter_geo for skymap instead of Earth

Tags: python, plotly, map-projections

I'm wanting to create an animated and interactive skymap using plotly, and I like scatter_geo (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter_geo) but it seems to only allow for the use with the Earth (hence "geo"). I like the functionality in general of scatter_geo, I just need to be able to map it to sky coordinates (because mapping to Earth's lat/long gets annoying with the Earth's rotation) and to be able to have an image of my choosing as the backdrop (I'm wanting to use the Planck image of the MW). Oh, and it needs to be able to do the Mollweide projection.

I'm basically trying to create something like this animation of Fast Radio Bursts (https://vimeo.com/146295242) but with different data and with more interactivity, and I think plotly has the features I need for that - if I can map my sources to the sky, that is!

Does anyone know either how to make scatter_geo do this, or an alternative I can use? I have not yet been able to find one. It doesn't need to be a plotly function, but I would prefer to stick with Python.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you found a solution for plotly/Dash @user1153070 ?

Answer (score 0):

...not sure how you create the flashes, but for the rest have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)

It can do all the stuff that `.scatter_geo` does, it should be able to handle any projection that [pyproj](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj) can handle and gives you a map in Mollweide projection if you want :-)

... and on top of that you can interact with the map and assign assign any callbacks you like.